# Export datatable to excel and pdf

Tags: javascript, html, datatables

I have a datatable, The information is in Oracle database.

This is the table
[image]

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#example').DataTable({
          dom: 'Bfrtip',
         "scrollY": "400px",
         "scrollCollapse": true,
         "paging": false,
         "searching": false,
         "ordering": false,
            buttons: [
                'excelHtml5',
                'pdfHtml5'
                    ]
           });
        } );
</script>
```

But, when trying to export the information to excel, it only shows me a single record.

[image]

In Dao

```
ArrayList<Tabla> list = new ArrayList<>();
    String sql = "SELECT APLICACION_ID,\n"
            + "SUM(CASE WHEN ESTADO_CASO = '6' THEN 1 END) as Pendiente,\n"
            + "SUM(CASE WHEN ESTADO_CASO = '7' THEN 1 END) as En_Proceso,\n"
            + "SUM(CASE WHEN ESTADO_CASO IN ('6', '7') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as total\n"
            + "FROM SERV_CASO\n"
            + "GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ( (APLICACION_ID), () )";
```

In Entity

```
public void setAPLICACION_ID(String APLICACION_ID) {
    this.APLICACION_ID = APLICACION_ID;
}
public String getEN_PROCESO() {
    return EN_PROCESO;
}
```

In HTML

```
<%MostrarTablaDao tablaDao = new MostrarTablaDao();
  List<Tabla> list = tablaDao.barCharData();
  Iterator<Tabla> iter = list.iterator();
  Tabla tabla = null;
  int i = 0;
  while (iter.hasNext()) {
  tabla = iter.next();%>

<tbody>
  <tr>
  <td><%= tabla.getAPLICACION_ID()%></td>                                   
  <td><%= tabla.getEN_PROCESO()%></td>
  </tr><%}%>
```

Browser console

[image]

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to show us how you populate the DataTable?

Comment: I think you should to load the data into the database first and then draw  the datatable.

Comment: You show us a `select` statement which (I am guessing) populates a Java list. But how do you populate the DataTable? Or, if my question is not clear: How do you populate the HTML `<table>` in the web page?

Comment: This is a project in controller, dao and entity

Comment: OK - but you need to show us how your code is doing this. Basically, we need a [mre] including details of any errors you see in the browser console. Without that, we can only make educated guesses. Just because data is being displayed in an HTML table, that does not mean the data is also contained in the JavaScript DataTables object. And DataTables will only export the data it contains.